# preg_match_all for special characters [?]

Tags: php, regex

I have a URL:

```
https://my.site.com/u/0/ac?export=download&amp;confirm=45vy&amp;id=qNhdhk1jejhXLexLpY3RiDY2oamis">D
```

And I want to match it using preg_match_all. My regex expression is:

```
preg_match_all('/(https:\/\/my\.site\.com\/[u]\/[0]\/(ac)\/(?)\/.*\">D)/', $input_lines, $output_array);
```

But I am not able to match special character `?` in above code. I tried using `(?)`. But it is not matching. I know it maybe a lame question, but if anyone could help me in matching `?` or in escaping `?` in preg_match_all, that would be helpfull.

Comment: Escape the character `\?`, just like you did with other character that have special meaning.

Comment: @JvdV You mean `(https:\/\/my\.site\.com\/[u]\/[0]\/(ac)\/.?\/.*\">D)` It is not working. The problem is I want to include `ac` in preg_match but I don't know how to escape or include `?`

Comment: You have a couple of errors (e.g. slashes in the wrong place, needless capture groups and character classes). Can you show what it is that you expect the output to be?

Comment: @Steven I want my output to be `https://my.site.com/u/0/ac?export=download&amp;confirm=45vy&amp;id=qNhdhk1jejhXLexLpY3RiDY2oamis">D`

Comment: Have you tried [parse url](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) instead?

Comment: Hello @TimMorton I am new to PHP. I don't understand  manual. I mostly do it using youtube. But there's no solution for it on youtube

Comment: just scroll down to the examples; that makes it easier to see what it does and how to use it. Believe me, the manual is your friend. I still refer to it often!

Comment: FWIW, I think parse_url is a much more stable approach for this problem. “If you have a problem and you solve it with a regex, you now have two problems”, as the saying goes ;)

Comment: Hello @TimMorton Thanks for your advice. I will surely check parse_url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just noticed that after ac there is not `/` in link but you are adding that in regex so just try to remove it or use the below code its working and tested.

```
<?php

$input_lines = 'https://my.site.com/u/0/ac?export=download&amp;confirm=45vy&amp;id=qNhdhk1jejhXLexLpY3RiDY2oamis">D';
preg_match_all('/(https:\/\/my\.site\.com\/[u]\/[0]\/(ac)(\?).*\">D)/', $input_lines, $output_array);

var_dump($output_array);
```

This is output - https://prnt.sc/weq86u

Or if there are chances that after `ac/?` can occur then you can try using `/` as optional parameter in regex

```
<?php

$input_lines = 'https://my.site.com/u/0/ac?export=download&amp;confirm=45vy&amp;id=qNhdhk1jejhXLexLpY3RiDY2oamis">D';
preg_match_all('/(https:\/\/my\.site\.com\/[u]\/[0]\/(ac)\/?(\?).*\">D)/', $input_lines, $output_array);

var_dump($output_array);
```

It will match both links with or without `/` https://prnt.sc/weqbae

Answer (score 2):

### Your regex

```
/(https:\/\/my\.site\.com\/[u]\/[0]\/(ac)\/(?)\/.*\">D)/
^                           ^    ^    ^   ^ ^    ^     ^
1                           2    2    3   4 5    6     1
+-- Starting delimiter      |    |    |   | |    |     +-- Ending delimiter
                            |    |    |   | |    +-- This is a greedy match and may not stop where intended
                            |    |    |   | +-- `?` is a special character in Regex and does nothing in this scenario; the .* is actually matching the `?`
                            |    |    |   +-- This slash doesn't exist
                            |    |    +-- No need for a capture group
                            +----+-- No need for a character set
```

1. Regular expression pattern delimiters:

   - ...mark the start and end of a pattern; similar to single/double quotes marking the start and end of strings
   - As with quotes if you use the delimiter in the pattern you have to escape it
   - To avoid escaping you can use a different delimiter

     ```
     Pattern 1: /https:\/\/www\.website\.com\/page\/1\/\index.php/

     Pattern 2: ~https://www\.website\.com/page/1/index\.php~
     ```

2.As you just want to match characters literally you can simply use the characters in the pattern. You would only need a character set if the character could be multiple values

```
   Set       Matched value
   u    ===> u
   [u]  ===> u
   [ua] ===> u OR a
```

3. Like with `2` you don't need a capture group here because you're only interested in capturing the whole string. This would add `$output_array[1] = "ac"` to your output
4. For some reason you're trying to match a `/` that doesn't exist in the URL so the pattern will never return anything
5. The `?` is a special character in regex; typically it is used at the start of a *group* (`a`), to modify a quantifier (`b`), or to imply a construct is *optional* (`c`). In this case `(?)` does absolutely nothing; the `.*` matches the literal `?` or would do if the slash wasn't in the pattern.

   a. Used in a group the `?` can mean, for example:

   ```
      (?:...) ===> Non-capturing group
      (?=...) ===> Positive lookahead
      (?!...) ===> Negative lookahead
   ```

   b. To modify a quantifier: usually a quantifier `+` or `*` would be *greedy* and matches as much as possible. Placing a `?` after it makes it non-greedy and stops at the first possibility

   ```
   String: IIIIOIIIOIIIO

   Pattern       Match

   /I.*O/        IIIIOIIIOIIIO
   /I.*?O/       IIIIO
   ```

   c. To make a construct optional

   ```
   Pattern                  Match 1             Match 2             Explanation

   ~https?://~              http://             https://            Optional character
   ~(?:www\.)?website.com~  website.com         www.website.com     Optional non-capturing group
   ```
6. As per `5b` this is a greedy quantifier so, for example, if the pattern `\">D` was to appear more than once in a string this would match until the last occurrence.

   - i.e. if there were more than one URL in your string then it would match from the first until the last as opposed to matching them individually

     ```
     String: <a href="website.com?id=2432546t4534">Link 1</a><a href="website.com?id=24345yr6787">Link 2</a>

     Pattern                    Matches

     ~website.com\?id=.*">~     [1] website.com?id=2432546t4534">Link 1</a><a href="website.com?id=24345yr6787">

     ~website.com\?id=.*?">~    [1] website.com?id=2432546t4534">
                                [2] website.com?id=24345yr6787">
     ```

### Fix

**Updated Regex**

```
~https://my\.site\.com/u/0/ac\?.*?">D~
~                                      : Starting delimiter
 https://my\.site\.com/u/0/ac          : Matches the initial part of the URL
                             \?        : Matches a literal ?
                               .*?     : Non-greedy match any character 0 or more times
                                  ">D  : Match string literally
                                     ~ : Ending delimiter
```

**Code**

```
$input_lines  = 'https://my.site.com/u/0/ac?export=download&amp;confirm=45vy&amp;id=qNhdhk1jejhXLexLpY3RiDY2oamis">D';

preg_match_all('~https://my\.site\.com/u/0/ac\?.*?">D~', $input_lines, $output_array);

print_r($output_array);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => https://my.site.com/u/0/ac?export=download&confirm=45vy&id=qNhdhk1jejhXLexLpY3RiDY2oamis">D
        )

)
```

Comment: Hello @Steven Thank You very much for your explanation. I really understood it in detail now.Thanks!